# Edit SQL server column data type

Tags: sql-server-2005

I've a an int column that I want to change to bigint but this column have alot of references
is there any way to alter the column and all referenced columns or I've to drop and recreate all constraints?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to drop and recreate primary key and foreign key constraints.